# Creating a custom message template in nopCommerce

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, templates, message, nopcommerce

I've written a method that collects some sales statistics that I would like to send as an email. I've searched through the project but I just can't figure out how to do this.

In the database there's a "MessageTemplates" -table with some information about the templates like "p" and "br" -tags with parameters like customer.name and so on. These templates seem to be implemented in "WorkflowMessageService" class. There's also a class called "MessageTokensProvider" but I can't see why I would need tokens as I just want the data collected from my method returned in the new mail.

Has anyone added a message template for nopCommerce before that can explain what I need to do and how it works? This would be very much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MessageTokensProvider is to allow certain token to be replaced with dynamic data. For example `%Store.Name%` will be replaced with the configured store name.

You can, of course, not use any tokens in your message template.

Comment: Ok i understand, thanks! Would it be sufficient just to create a new method in WorkflowMessageService and call the method i wan't from there in order to have an email sent or is it more to it? Do i have to add the Db-table in MessageTemplates as well? Thx

Comment: If you do not need to replace tokens, it's even better (and more straightforward) that you send the e-mail directly. Have a look at ContactUs() method in CommonController. It sends the e-mail directly without going through WorkflowMessageService. :)

Comment: Thanks wooncherk, i'll check that out =)